# dynamically setting alpha to background image of the layout is not taking effect

Tags: android, layout, alpha

I'm developing for api 15. I have a layout with a background image and a button. When the button is pressed background image should change alpha to 150. But it isn't taking effect. Do I have to somehow force update on layout so that it does take effect?
Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/wall1Layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wall1withkey"
    tools:context=".FireRoomActivity" >
<Button ...
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in main activity there is a method that supposed to respond to onClick from the button:

```
public void buttonClicked(View v)
{
findViewById(R.id.wall1Layout).getBackground().setAlpha(180);;
}
```

So the image wall1withkey should change alpha to 180

Answer (score 0):

When i tried to create translucent background i used my own custom Theme.

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Then you have to set this `Theme.Transparent` to your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.TransparentActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: nice. but i've got to apply it only on button click, at run time. any ideas how to do that?

Comment: your background will become translucent only when u set alpha to it